# Change variables' names in excel sheets using R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, gsub

I would like to change the variables' names in an excel sheet using R. For instance, in the attached screenshot, I want to replace "pata" with /t/, "pada" with /d/, and "paca" with /c/. I used sub and gsub functions of R to make changes in my csv file but I would prefer to replace all the names in my df and then export the df as a csv file.

```
df<- read_csv("change_variables_names.csv")
sub('pata','/t/', df$Word)
gsub('pata','/t/', df$Word)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

data %>% 
  mutate(Word = case_when(Word == "pata" ~ "/t/",
                          Word == "pada" ~ "/d/",
                          Word == "paca" ~ "/c/")) %>% 
  write.csv(., "new_variable_names.csv")
```

Here is a solution with `base R` using `lapply` and `gsub`:

```
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) gsub("pata", "/t/", x)))
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) gsub("pada", "/d/", x)))
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) gsub("paca", "/c/", x)))

write.csv(data, "new_variables.csv")
```

Either way gives us:

```
 Word Repetition Value
1  /t/          1   233
2  /t/          2   433
3  /t/          3   552
4  /d/          1   234
5  /d/          2   567
6  /d/          3   436
7  /c/          1   765
8  /c/          2   231
9  /c/          3   567
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Word = c("pata", "pata", "pata", "pada", "pada", 
"pada", "paca", "paca", "paca"), Repetition = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3), Value = c(233, 433, 552, 234, 567, 436, 765, 231, 
567)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```